# Is the quotient of a scheme by the free action of an elliptic curve an algebraic space?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, stacks, group-actions

Let $X$ be a scheme (I'm happy to assume that $X$ is of finite type, separated, and over $\mathbb{C}$) and let $E$ be an elliptic curve which acts freely on $X$. Does the quotient stack $[X/E]$ have the structure of an algebraic space?

The Luna slice theorem seems to only apply to reductive groups so I don't see how to get etale charts for this kind of quotient in general. It seems like a related question is whether there exists a coarse moduli space for a stack like $[X/E]$. I would expect that this stack is equivalent to its coarse moduli space, but I don't see how to prove the coarse space exists in this case. I was not able to find much in the literature about quotients by groups like $E$.

Comment: I think the Keel-Mori theorem makes no assumptions on the group scheme. Also, one can probably construct the quotient as a quasi-projective variety (if $X$ is quasi-projective) as the subscheme of the Hilbert scheme which parametrises the $E$ orbits.

Comment: Why Keel-Mori? The original Artin theorem proves that the quotient fppf sheaf, which since there are no stabilizers is also the quotient stack [X/E], is an algebraic space. See e.g. Artin, The implicit function theorem in algebraic geometry, Thm 7.1.

Comment: Hi Matthieu. Thanks for the answer. If you post it as an answer instead of a comment, I can accept it.

Comment: @ulrich Good point about constructing the quotient as a Hilbert scheme. Thanks.